# What can you use to cast an int/float to a wchar_t*?

Tags: c++

If you have an `int` or `float`, how can you cast it to a `wchar_t*` without using external libraries like boost?

Answer (score 5):

```
std::wostringstream oss;
int i = 1212;  // or float f = 1212.0f;
oss<<i;        // oss<<f;

std::wstring ws = oss.str();
const wchar_t* cwp = ws.c_str(); // const wchar_t*

std::vector<wchar_t> buf( cwp , cwp + (wc.size() + 1) );
wchar_t* wp = &buf[0];  // wchar_t*
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast it meaningfully:

```
int x = 43;
wchar_t *ptr = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t *>(x);
```

This will compile, but it has no meaning. It simply re-interprets the integer value and forces the creation of a pointer with that value. Since there is nothing valid for you access at the address, it is meaningless and useless.

If you mean "convert", there is probably a wide-character version of snprintf() you can use, e.g. `snwprintf()` or similar. This might depend a bit on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly casting, but I suspect you want to have a string representation. `printf`-family functions or stringstreams may be of help. Why would you want to *cast* it to `wchar_t` is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, in conjunction to hacker's answer above

```
int num1 = 25;
float fnum1 = 3.14;
char buf[50];
sprintf(buf, "Int: %d. Float: %4.2f", num1, fnum1);
```

The only thing you have to be careful is to ensure you have enough sufficient space in the buffer for the `sprintf` function to work, otherwise you will get an overflow and corrupt another area of memory which will crash your program.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: By the way, why do you want to cast it to a type that has underlying type of char * family? Can you clarify a bit more in what you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: My XML classes handle things in wchar_t*.  I have an integer that I'd like to write to my xml file.

Comment: @Mark:  Writing an integer to a file is a far different thing from casting it to a pointer value.