# cast float to wchar_t win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2012

It freaks me out that I cannot find anyway to cast float to wchar_t or maybe I was looking in the wrong places!

```
 float cNumbers[9]  = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0};
 float x            = 3.0;
 float temp     = 0.0;
 wchar_t data[]     = {0};

 for(int i=0; i < sizeof(cNumbers); i++){

    temp = x / cNumbers[i];
    bool isInt = temp == static_cast<int>(temp);

    if(isInt){
        data =  temp; //this is a big fail
        addToList(hWnd,data);
    }
  }

void addToList(HWND hWnd,const wchar_t * data ){

  SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_LISTBOX),LB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)data); 
}
```

the problem is i want to convert float value to wchar_t to send it to listbox

Comment: With VS2012 you can also use `std::to_wstring(x)` to convert to a `wstring`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can you use to cast an int/float to a wchar\_t\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860945/what-can-you-use-to-cast-an-int-float-to-a-wchar-t)

Answer (score 5):

In C++, casting PODs will reinterpret the binary data as the casted-to type and not do the kind of type conversion that you want to accomplish.

You have a couple of options here:

- You can use `boost::lexical_cast` for a cast-like conversion
- You can use `wsprintf` or a `std::wstringstream` to handle the conversion from float to wide string
- If you are using MFC/ATL, you can use CString::Format to convert the float into a string

The second option is the only one that doesn't use a third-party library so if you are restricted in what you can use library wise, you're stuck with either `wsprintf` or std::wstringstream. Normally my recommendation in that case would be to use std::wstringstream for both type safety reasons and protections from buffer overflows.

Answer (score 3):

There already is an answer: [What can you use to cast an int/float to a wchar_t*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860945/what-can-you-use-to-cast-an-int-float-to-a-wchar-t)

Just use:

```
float x = 0.0f;

std::wostringstream woss;
woss << x;       
std::wstring ws = woss.str();
const wchar_t* cwc = ws.c_str();
std::vector<wchar_t> buf( cwc , cwc + (ws.size() + 1) );
wchar_t* x2 = &buf[0];
```